# Trouble clipping two vector layers (EPSG is the same in both)

Tags: qgis

I am trying to clip a layer but it gives empty output (No error message, just an empty layer)

The desired input layer is a hexagonal grid (148980 features) created in MMQGIS in EPSG: 32629.

The clipping layer is a layer that I created myself, by merging two line vectors and then using the tool Lines to Polygons, also in EPSG: 32629, which you can see below.

[image: clipping layer]

Both layers are quite large, since they represent a portion of the Exclusive Economic zone of Portugal (around 100 000km2)

I'm working in QGIS 2.18.16

Comment: Clip sometimes is a bitch, try intersect.

Comment: Try running the **Geometry Checker** tool to check if your layer is valid.

Comment: try clipping with a smaller polygon first.

Comment: @ErikLohmann Intersect gave me an invalid features error (Even when I selected to Ignore Null geometries). I tried to check the geometry as Joseph recommended and I found out that my grid layer is okay, but the test in my self-drawn vector layer crashed my computer so I suppose that would be the issue. I am going to create a new one and see what happens. Thanks for the input!