# Trouble with Difference/Symmetrical Difference Tool - Empty output

Tags: qgis

I'm having issues trying to eliminate overlapping parts of two polygons.
The aim is to delete the parts of the pink layer that overlap with the green one. I tried using difference tool and symmetrical tool, however, both are producing an empty result (EPSG is the same)

Any ideas why this would be happening?
Also, if there are any alternative tools, can someone suggest them?[image: Case]

EDIT: I managed to fix it. There was a small intersection error in the layer that I checked with the Geometry Checker Plugin. After deleting that small error, the difference output was correct.

Comment: Try running `v.clean` from the GRASS toolbox, see if maybe there's an issue with the input layers.

Comment: These might be related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274437/trouble-clipping-two-vector-layers-epsg-is-the-same-in-both

Comment: @JoshC Unfortunately GRASS plugins do not work on my laptop but that's a problem for another day. However, a simple geometry check managed to fix the problem! Thanks for the input though, i will keep it in mind once I fix the GRASS issue.